# Do pointwise convergence and norm boundedness imply Lp convergece?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces, pointwise-convergence

Suppose that $f_n,f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $f_n \to f$ pointwise everywhere. In addition, assume there is some $C_p > 0$ independent of $n$ so that $||f_n||_p \leq C_p ||f||_p$ for all $n$. Is it true that $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$?

I am not sure whether we can use the dominated convergence theorem since we do not have $|f_n| \leq g$ with $g \in L^p$ here.

Context: I am studying *Fourier Integrals in Classical Analysis, 2nd Edition* by Sogge. In the proof of **Corollary 2.3.2**, it seems to me that we need the proposition above.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure they are using that result, because it is not true in general.

Comment: There is a generalised DCT but that is not in play here.

Comment: May be requiring some monotonicity is enough ? (But the inequality hypothesis seems too much in this case)

Comment: For $1 < p < \infty$, the hypotheses guarantee that $f_n$ converges _weakly_ to $f$. You cannot conclude norm-convergence. Let $g \neq 0$ be a continuous function with compact support, and $f_n(x) = f(x) + g(x - ny)$ for a fixed $y \neq 0$. Then $f_n \to f$ pointwise, and $\lVert f_n - f\rVert_p = \lVert g\rVert_p$ for all $n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for your comment. This is a nice counterexample.

Comment: @copper.hat Now I think the proposition in the question is not true. I will rethink how they prove the corollary there.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect there is something wrong with the statement of the proposition Let $p=1$. On $(0,1)$ define $f_n(x)= n +x$ if $0<x<\frac  1 n$ and $f_n(x)=x$ otherwise. Let $f(x)=x$ for all $n$. Then the hypothesis is satisfied but $\int |f_n-f| =1$ for all $n$.

Comment: This is a nice example. Specifically, $||f|| = 1/2$ and $||f_n|| = 3/2$, so the hypothesis is satisfied. Thank you!

Comment: If we assume that $f_n \to f$ uniformly as $n \to \infty$, will the above assertion be true?

Comment: @b04902072 No uniform convergence is also not a sufficient condition. Take for example $f_n =f+\frac  1n I_{(0,n)}$  with $p=d=1$.