# $L^p$ Convergence of Riesz Means for Schwartz functions

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

For $\delta > 0$ and $\lambda>0$, define the Riesz means of $f$ by
$$
S_\lambda^\delta f(x)= (2\pi)^{-n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{i\langle x,\xi\rangle}(1 - |\xi/\lambda|)_+^\delta\hat{f}(\xi)d\xi,
$$ where $t_+^\delta = t^\delta$ for $t>0$ and zero otherwise. Define the critical index for $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$
$$
\delta(p) = \max\left\{n\left|\frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{p}\right| - \frac{1}{2},0\right\}.
$$

Assume that (1) $n\geq 3$ and $p \in [1,\frac{2(n+1)}{n+3}]\cup [\frac{2(n+1)}{n-1},\infty],$ or
(2) $n=2$ and $1\leq p \leq \infty.$ Suppose we know that $$\|S_\lambda^\delta f\|_{L^p(\mathbb R^n)} \leq C_{p,\delta}\|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb R^n)}$$ for all $\lambda>0$, where $f\in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ and $\delta > \delta(p).$

Let $g \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^n),$ i.e., a Schwartz function. Show that $S_\lambda^\delta g \to g$ in $L^p$ as $\lambda \to \infty$ for $\delta > \delta(p).$

I already knew that $S_\lambda^\delta g \to g$ pointwise everywhere, by the Fourier inversion formula. I tried to show [this Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3474687/do-pointwise-convergence-and-norm-boundedness-imply-lp-convergece), but it turns out to be false.

Context: I am studying $\S$ **2.3 Riesz Means in** $\mathbb R^n$ in *Fourier Integrals In Classical Analysis, 2nd Edition* by Sogge. The above assertion is needed in the proof of **Corollary 2.3.2**.

Comment: This is a kind of a general principle; a "maximal estimate" implies pointwise convergence. (A maximal estimate is one like the one you have here, "maximal" refers to it being uniform in $\lambda$). The mechanism of proof is adapted from the proof of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, for which the maximal estimate is the classic weak estimate for the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks. I edited my question.

Comment: From this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.3087.pdf, it seems that you might find something in  chapter 9 of `E.M. Stein, Harmonic Analysis, Real-variable methods, orthogonality and oscillatory integrals, Princeton Univ. Press, Princeton 1993.` and also `K. M. Davis and Y. Chang, Lectures on Bochner-Riesz means, London Mathematical Society, Lecture Note Series 114, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge (1987).`

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks for your references. I will consult those books.